# Como copiar um arquivo .txt codificado para outro decodificado usando AssignFile?

Tags: delphi, txt

Tenho um arquivo .txt codificado e preciso copiar o conteúdo decodificado para outro .txt.

No primeiro arquivo, tenho o seguinte:

> GcbqRM5mNp4
>
> GcbqRM5mNp8
>
> GcbqRM5mNpC

Quando o novo arquivo é criado, ele está retornando o número de linhas correto, mas somente com o primeiro item da lista decodificado:

> Bitmap_1
>
> Bitmap_1
>
> Bitmap_1

E o retorno deveria ser:

> Bitmap_1
>
> Bitmap_2
>
> Bitmap_3

O código que estou usando:

```
var
arq, arqDec : TextFile;
linha, nome : string;
s : Integer;

     begin  //Decodifica o texto do arquivo
     AssignFile(arq, FrmCadastro.CBUsuario.Text +'-images.txt');
     Reset(arq);
     while not Eof(arq) do
       begin
       Readln(arq, linha);
       s := Pos(Encode64('Bitmap_'), linha);
       nome := Copy(linha, 1, s-1);
       Delete(linha, 1, s);
       ShowMessage(Decode64(linha)); //<--Até aqui dá o retorno correto (ShowMessage usado só pra testar)
       end;

       begin
       AssignFile(arqDec, FrmCadastro.CBUsuario.Text +'-Decod-images.txt');
       if not (FileExists(FrmCadastro.CBUsuario.Text +'-Decod-images.txt')) then
       Rewrite(arqDec)
       else
         Begin
         Append(arqDec);
         Writeln(arqDec, Decode64(linha));                
       end;
     end;

     CloseFile(arq);
     CloseFile(arqDec);
    end;
```

O que estou fazendo de errado? Ou o que está faltando pra gravar os dados corretos no novo arquivo .txt?

Comment: Nelson, você está escrevendo no arquivo fora do loop que lê o arquivo de origem. Tente melhorar a endentação que fica fácil perceber, ok?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nelson, se você quer criar um arquivo com o conteúdo exibido pelo ShowMessage, então acho que você deve criar esse arquivo no início, antes do looping, e executar o Writeln no mesmo ponto onde você acrescentou o ShowMessage:

```
var
  arq, arqDec : TextFile;
  linha {, nome} : string;
  s : Integer;
begin  //Decodifica o texto do arquivo
  AssignFile(arqDec, FrmCadastro.CBUsuario.Text +'-Decod-images.txt');
  Rewrite(arqDec);
  try
    AssignFile(arq, FrmCadastro.CBUsuario.Text +'-images.txt');
    Reset(arq);
    try
      while not Eof(arq) do
        begin
          Readln(arq, linha);
          s := Pos(Encode64('Bitmap_'), linha);
          // nome := Copy(linha, 1, s-1);
          Delete(linha, 1, s);
          // ShowMessage(Decode64(linha)); //<--Até aqui dá o retorno correto (ShowMessage usado só pra testar)
          Writeln(arqDec, Decode64(linha));                
        end;
    finally
      CloseFile(arq);
    end;
  finally
    CloseFile(arqDec);
  end;
end;
```

Espero que ajude

Answer (score 0):

Você esta com um claro problema de indentação.

Observe este parte do seu código:

```
 while not Eof(arq) do
   begin
   Readln(arq, linha);
   s := Pos(Encode64('Bitmap_'), linha);
   nome := Copy(linha, 1, s-1);
   Delete(linha, 1, s);
   ShowMessage(Decode64(linha)); //<--Até aqui dá o retorno correto (ShowMessage usado só pra testar)
   end;
```

O correto seria:

```
 while not Eof(arq) do
 begin
   Readln(arq, linha);
   s := Pos(Encode64('Bitmap_'), linha);
   nome := Copy(linha, 1, s-1);
   Delete(linha, 1, s);
   ShowMessage(Decode64(linha)); //<--Até aqui dá o retorno correto (ShowMessage usado só pra testar)
 end;
```

O que estiver dentro do *begin e end;* do *while not Eof(arq) do* será executado em repetição.

Portanto, tente:

```
 while not Eof(arq) do
 begin
   Readln(arq, linha);
   s := Pos(Encode64('Bitmap_'), linha);
   nome := Copy(linha, 1, s-1);
   Delete(linha, 1, s);
   ShowMessage(Decode64(linha)); //<--Até aqui dá o retorno correto (ShowMessage usado só pra testar)

   AssignFile(arqDec, FrmCadastro.CBUsuario.Text +'-Decod-images.txt');

   if not (FileExists(FrmCadastro.CBUsuario.Text +'-Decod-images.txt')) then
     Rewrite(arqDec)
   else
   begin
     Append(arqDec);
     Writeln(arqDec, Decode64(linha));                
   end;
 end;
```

Comment: Ainda tenho muito que aprender... o erro era realmente a endentação. @imex, o seu código deu certo, mas tem um problema, quando é um arquivo novo não grava na hora, preciso fechar o programa (só mudar de tela pra pegar outro arquivo não resolve) e só quando abro novamente ele salva o arquivo decodificado. Mas não sei se é problema do meu PC ou do programa em si mesmo, vou testar mais um pouco.

Comment: Junior Moreira, o seu código me dá um retorno de "I/O error 32" e não salva o arquivo decodificado, deve ter faltado alguma coisa, mas não tive tempo de ver ainda.

Comment: Nelson, acho que isso não deveria ocorrer. Certifique-se de que o CloseFile está sendo executado (vou editar o código sugerido anteriormente para acrescentar um try / finally / end e dessa forma assegurar a execução do CloseFile) e de que o arquivo não está sendo gravado em uma pasta protegida

Comment: @imex, com o try / finally / end a mais o código está funcionando direito. Apesar de ser uma dúvida boba (reconheço), e que muitos ignoram e acham que não precisa ser respondida, ajudou bastante. Estou aprendendo por conta própria a mexer no Delphi e mesmo pesquisando e lendo bastante ainda tenho alguma dificuldade. Agradeço imensamente pela ajuda de todos.